# Reflection: Throws java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, reflection

```
1.for (Field field : fields) {
2.    if (p.contains(field.getName())) {
3.        if(field.getType().toString().split("[.]")[2].equals("String"))
4.            callableStatement.setString(field.getName(), field.get(obj).toString());
5.        else if(field.getType().toString().split("[.]")[2].equals("Integer"))
6.            callableStatement.setInt(field.getName(), (int)field.get(obj));
7.        System.out.println(field.get(obj).toString());
8.    }
9.}
```

This is my code. Using reflection I fetch the data from the class object and in the above loop, I set parameters for the procedure input. However, it saves some integer values and throws `java.lang.NullPointerException` for some on line number 7.

These values are accepted:

```
this.DI_StDate = Common.getDateStamp(date); // Integer
this.DI_StTime = Common.getTimeStamp(date); // Integer
```

From Common.java

```
public static Integer getDateStamp(Date d) {
    return Integer.parseInt(requiredDate.format(d));
}

public static Integer getTimeStamp(Date d) {
    return Integer.parseInt(requiredTime.format(d));
}
```

These throws the exception:

```
this.FileOpsId = new Integer(1);            // Integer
this.FileTypeOpsId = 1;                     // Integer
```

Please suggest where I am going wrong.

These are my class members:

```
public class DIConnect {
    public Integer PROC_ID;
    public String APIKey;
    public String Username;
    public String pwd;
    public String StreamKey;

    public Integer DI_StDate;
    public Integer DI_StTime;

    public String FileNamePath;
    public Integer FileOpsTypeId;
    public String ConfigLabel;
    public Integer FileOpsId;

    public Integer End_Date;
    public Integer End_Time;

    public DIConnect(String FileNamePath, String ConfigLabel, Integer FileOpsTypeId, Integer StartDate, Integer StartTime) {
        this.FileNamePath = FileNamePath;
        this.ConfigLabel = ConfigLabel;
        this.FileOpsTypeId = FileOpsTypeId;
        this.DI_StDate = StartDate; // accepted
        this.DI_StTime = StartTime; // accepted
        this.FileOpsId = new Integer(1); // NOT ACCEPTED
    }
}
```

This is the call in the main() method.

```
DIConnect DIC = new DIConnect(filePath, "File", 1, Common.getDateStamp(date), Common.getTimeStamp(date));
DIC.InsertFileOperation();
```

DIConnect.java:

```
public Integer InsertFileOperation() {
        String[] params = {"FileNamePath", "FileOpsId", "ConfigLabel", "DI_StDate", "DI_StTime"};
        DatabaseOperation db = new DatabaseOperation();
        if(db.openConnection()) {
            this.PROC_ID = db.executeProcedure("sp_InsertIntoFileOpsMaster", params, this);
            db.closeConnection();
        }
        return this.PROC_ID;
    }
```

Database.java

```
public Integer executeProcedure(String proc, String[] params, Object obj) {
        int Id = 0;
        try {
            String paramString = StringUtils.repeat("?, ", params.length + 1).trim();
            paramString = paramString.substring(0, paramString.length() - 1);
            proc = "{CALL " + proc + "(" + paramString + ")}";
            callableStatement = conn.prepareCall(proc);

            Class cls = obj.getClass();
            Field[] fields = cls.getFields();
            List<String> p = Arrays.asList(params);

            for (Field field : fields) {
                if (p.contains(field.getName())) {
                    if(field.getType().toString().split("[.]")[2].equals("String"))
                        callableStatement.setString(field.getName(), field.get(obj).toString());
                    else if(field.getType().toString().split("[.]")[2].equals("Integer"))
                        callableStatement.setInt(field.getName(), (int)field.get(obj));
                    System.out.println(field);                        
//                    System.out.println(field.get(obj).toString());
                }
            }
            callableStatement.registerOutParameter("Id",java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
            callableStatement.executeUpdate();
            Id = callableStatement.getInt("Id");

        } catch (SQLException | IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DatabaseOperation.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (Exception ex){
          System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        } finally {
            return Id;
        }
    }
```

OUTPUT

```
public java.lang.Integer airteldemo.DIConnect.DI_StDate
public java.lang.Integer airteldemo.DIConnect.DI_StTime
public java.lang.String airteldemo.DIConnect.FileNamePath
public java.lang.String airteldemo.DIConnect.ConfigLabel
null
```

Comment: What's the result if you try to print the `field`?

Comment: `field.getName()` gives the name of the field i.e. FileOpsId and FileTypeOpsId. Also, `(int)field.get(obj).value` gives the value

Comment: I just say please try to print `field` : (System.out.print(field)) exactly at the line in which you get the exception and see what's the result.

Comment: It returns a `null`, whereas for other fields it is returning an object.

Comment: CallableStatement is not a field in this object. It is in another class.

Comment: If you want to make this code more tractable you should show the execution flow of the code:e.g. I have method m that calls method n, in method n I have this for loop ,... . In addition, please show the related parts of the code. How should we understand the relation of this constructor with your for loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the bug. The callablestatement fetches the signature for the called procedure. The parameters should be passed as case-sensitive parameters. My procedure was recieving them as `FileOpsTypeID` and I was passing `FileOpsTypeId`. Changing the case made it work.

Sorry for the delayed response. Also sorry, I didn't provide the complete details (procedure).

Answer (score 1):

As I guessed the `field.get(obj)` (sometimes) returns `null` so you should check if it's `null` or somehow (depending on the logic of your code) don't allow it to become `null`.

I post this as answer cause given the information you've provided we can just tell you where is the problem, not what is causing it.

Comment: I suggest you to ask another question, or just add the required information to your post (not as a comment), so that everyone (including me) can understand it properly.

Comment: How can `field` be null when `if (p.contains(field.getName())) {` executed normally?

Comment: @MikeSamuel> Nice, I didn't notice that, so the only option is `field.get(obj)` is null.

Comment: @MikeSamuel> The op has been added the rest of code, so I'm looking at the code, so I may change my answer soon.

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with your code.

---

First, fields can have null values in java.  If you're taking an argument of type `Object` you just have to accept this and map `null` values to SQL values perhaps based on reasoning about the database column type.

Instead of using `field.get(obj).toString()` which doesn't work with `null` field values, use `String.valueOf(field.get(obj))`

---

Second

```
else if(field.getType().toString().split("[.]")[2].equals("Integer"))
```

is broken because it assumes `java.lang.Integer` so could fail with a ClassCastException, is not null safe because `(Integer) null` does not correspond to any `int` value, and it could fail with an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` when `field.getType()` is something like `shortpackage.Integer`.

Instead do

```
Integer.class.equals(field.getType()) || Integer.TYPE.equals(field.getType())
```

`Integer.TYPE` is the pseudo-class for the `int` primitive type.

---

Third, you seem to be writing your own database abstraction layer.  There's plenty of ORBs out there which should do this for you.  I encourage you to use one of those instead.

Comment: Hmm... I am passing the default values for the integer types that are generating the exception. I will take your advice of using external products. But, is your answer in anyways an answer to my solution?

Comment: @SameerAnand, the root of your problem is that `field.get(obj)` can be null if `!field.getType().isPrimitive()`.  Since it can be null, you need to plan for null results.

Comment: One small thing, i will fail with `NullPointerException` instead of `ClassCastException`. The class cast exception would be if you have not numeric type. As is delivered from `Number` then it is unboxed via calling `.intValue()` and this raise NPE.